# How to add dynamic fields in React with data (Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this layout

[image]

**DESIRED BEHAVIOUR**

In the start there is only one input. First one. And it is empty. When i type something in it and press 'ADD +' new input under that one is created , it is disabled and it has value of first one that I was typing in. First one is then cleared and it is empty again. I really have no idea how to make this.

---

---

This is the code that I currently have.

```js
const FilterListInput = ({ data }) => {
  const [comp, setComp] = useState('');
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([[]]);

  console.log(rows);

  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    rows[index] = e.target.value;
    setRows(rows);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="filter__form__elements__element">
        <label htmlFor={data.name}>{data.labelName}</label>
        <For
          of={rows}
          render={(item, index) => (
            <>
              <Input
                name={item.name}
                placeholder={data.placeholder}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
              />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </div>
      <Button title="ADD +" type="secondary" onClick={() => setRows([...rows, comp])} />
    </>
  );
};
```

I am stuck here and I have no idea where to go next. Currently when I create new input I can type in it and data from the first one is left in it which I don't want. Also I want everything to be saved in `rows` hook.

I am not asking for full code. Just some guidlines.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I understand your desired behaviour -> 
1. you want to start with one empty input, and when pressing the + button, you want to add a new empty input to the start of the list. 
2. all inputs but the first one should be disabled.

I don't think you need the comp state, only the rows state.
rows state should be 1D array (not 2D)

- state should be init with one empty string `const [rows,setRows] = useState([''])`
- when rendering the inputs if index > 0 input should be disabled.
- when pressing the + button you need to add a new row to the start
  `setRows['',...rows]`
- on your handleChange function just make sure you are replacing the
  array so the component will rerender. something like

  `const handleChange = (e, index) => {
     const newRows = [...rows];
     newRows[index] = e.target.value;
     setRows(newRows);   };`

hope it helps